# Integration and data upload - MuleSoft CloudHub to Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api, mulesoft, mule4, mule-component, tableau-desktop

I am using MuleSoft CloudHub with Runtime v4.4 to upload CSV data to Tableau Server. The documentation page https://docs.mulesoft.com/tableau-specialist-connector/1.1/ confirms that its not possible to use Hyper Configuration and its operations in CloudHub because CloudHub does not allow executing external code due to security reasons. That is why I am trying to use REST configurations and it's available operations.

With all my attempts, I am able to connect to Tableau server and successfully perform simple operations like Initial file upload, Query project, Append to file upload, etc. But, these operations does not help to publish my CSV content to Tableau. Publish workbook operation also requires file content in *.twbx format, and I am not sure how to convert CSV/JSON/XML to TWBX content type.

I have referred some websites and MuleSoft technical videos where HTTPS connection can be used to upload data to Tableau but those examples are using *.hyper file from classpath.

So, basically I am stuck at 2 different paths:

1. How can I transform CSV content to hyper file content in Mule flow. If this transform is possible then I can use HTTPS connection to Tableau and upload my data.
2. Using MuleSoft Tableau connector v1.1 and with REST configurations, is it possible to upload data to Tableau?

If there is any other solution, then I am happy to change my implementation strategy. Please can somebody guide me to correct direction?

Comment: I don't know about mule flows but it looks like it has a python component. You can create a hyper with the Hyper API and upload it with Tableau Server Client API.

Comment: I received below response from MuleSoft Support team, and looks like there is no easy way of uploading/publishing *.csv files to Tableau.

Locally the following solution should work: 
- Use the Tableau connector to get Hyper Configuration 
- Using a File connector -> Write the CSV to file path

Cloudhub: 
- The hyper configuration is not supported, as the documentation suggest
- Custom java transformation to get hyper file and then use the http listener